# Connecting to cloudSQL (MySQL) with python script using SSL certificates

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-sql

I need to connect a python script to the Google Cloud SQL database using SSL. I am aware how to connect to the database only by ip address but I do not understand how to use the SSL certificate (3 `.pem` certificates), token ID etc that I have received in the `.json` file using python. I have tried some codes and they do not work nor do I understand what is going on.

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
import os
import stat
from google.cloud import storage

def main():
    con = connect()
    connection = con.connect_to_db()
    result = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM 
       personaformation').fetchall()
    for row in result:
        votes.append({
            'fname': row[0],
            'lname': row[1],
            'email': row[2]
        })
    print(votes[0])

def connect_to_db(self):

    # Get keys from GCS
    client = storage.Client()

    bucket = client.get_bucket(weightssl)
    bucket.get_blob('C:/Users/tasne/Downloads/serverca.pem').
    download_to_filename('server-ca.pem')
    
    bucket.get_blob('C:/Users/tasne/Downloads/clientkey.pem').
    download_to_filename('client-key.pem')
    os.chmod("client-key.pem", stat.S_IRWXU)
    bucket.get_blob('C:/Users/tasne/Downloads/clientcert.pem').
    download_to_filename('client-cert.pem')

    sslrootcert = 'server-ca.pem'
    sslkey = 'client-key.pem'
    sslcert = 'client-cert.pem'

    print("reached here")

    con = psycopg2.connect(
        host='37.246.65.223',
        dbname='personalformation',
        user='hello',
        password='world',
        sslmode = 'verify-full',
        sslrootcert=sslrootcert,
        sslcert=sslcert,
        sslkey=sslkey)
    return con
```

When I try the codes this is the error that I get, however I do not know where to specify the credentials nor am I using compute engine because this is not an application that I am creating but only a python script

```
C:\Users\tasne\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/tasne/Downloads/database2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tasne/Downloads/database2.py", line 21, in <module>
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
  File "C:\Users\tasne\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1288, in get_application_default
    return GoogleCredentials._get_implicit_credentials()
  File "C:\Users\tasne\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1278, in _get_implicit_credentials
    raise ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError(ADC_HELP_MSG)
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Comment: Did you follow what the error message tells you? That is, did you set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the path to the file containing your credentials? More info following the [link provided](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#setting_the_environment_variable) by the error

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez  No ,because i didnot know where to put it

Comment: Try following the [instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#setting_the_environment_variable) wherever you are running your script.

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez will try it